# Why does my iOS project Gemfile bundle update unconsistently?

Tags: ios, bundler, gemfile, gemfile.lock, jazzy

I have a simple `Gemfile` for an iOS project using cocoapods:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'cocoapods'
gem 'fastlane'
gem 'jazzy'
```

I've tried to update my bundle by a `bundle update` and jazzy went from version 0.8.2 to 0.0.14 so I rolled back my `Gemfile.lock` and did 3 invidual updates of my 3 gems and everything went *fine*, ie jazzy was still in version 0.8.2.

I redid a `bundle update` and, again, jazzy went from version 0.8.2 to 0.0.14.

What am I missing here? Why do I get a different set of versions with the same constraints?

A gist with more details about the content of the files: https://gist.github.com/dirtyhenry/135ec7ef73f873d5ac3236bc3da633ba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is dependency hell.

Fastlane depends on `xcpretty`, which depends on `rouge` of major version 2 (~>2.0.7) and jazzy itself depends on different versions of `rouge`, major version 1 (~> 1.5) so, bundler tries to resolve highest version of jazzy to reuse existing rouge dependency (which is 0.0.14).

However, you can force bundler to use version 0.8.2 an more of jazzy, add to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'jazzy', '>=0.8.2'
```

instead of

```
gem 'jazzy'
```

And perform `bundle update` again.

See more details on versioning in [bundler docs](http://bundler.io/gemfile.html)

Comment: "bundle update will update all gems to the latest version" that's what I want but that's not what it does. Jazzy is downgraded to 0.0.14.